# Changing around the format of an input that's a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a program ask for a name in the format `Last, First, Middle.` And then you output it as `First, Middle, Last.`

```
    Name = raw_input("Enter your name as Last First Middle: ")
    Name.find[" "]=  "x"
```

What I am trying to do is find the first blank and make that number a variable, then print the string from the first blank on, then add the beginning of the string to the blank which would give him name back in the correct order. Only problem is that I am getting an error that says

> TypeError: 'buildin_function_or_method' Object does not support item
>   assignment.

Just want to know why I cant insert the number of finding the first blank as a variable.

Comment: `Name.find` is a method, as such call it with `Name.find(" ")`. I doubt assigning anything to it would work... try `Name.find("x")` instead

Comment: Yeah I just cant assign the number resulting from Name.find to a variable without an error popping up which is my problem.

Comment: if I understand correctly, then you want `x = Name.find(" ")`, where `x` shows you the position of the first space

Comment: Im very new to this and yes this works perfectly fine. I just had it in the wrong order. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need parenthesis to pass argument to a method so you need :

```
Name.find(" ")
```

Secondly you can't assigned to a method call, and if you want to replace a character in a string you can simply use `str.replace` method :

```
Name.replace(" ","x")
```

Comment: thirdly use lowercase to name variables :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I think your solution to this is a little overcomplicated. Check out the code below which does what you'd like to do pretty easily.

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name as Last First Middle: ")
last, first, middle = name.split()
print first, middle, last
```

Comment: using `.split()` works just as well, on any whitespace

Comment: @Pynchia Doh! Totally forgot! Thanks dude, edited the answer.

Comment: Yes this is much simpler than what I was trying to do. Just for future reference is there any possible way you can assign the value of any str.find(" ") to a variable?

Comment: see my last comment above, to your original post